# Using object within Internet Explorer 8 (IE8)?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I have a video on a webpage that works in all browsers other than IE8 and IE7.  Is this code not supported on those browsers?

```
<object class="video-frame" data="http://www.youtube.com/videofile" height="215" width="280"></object>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to w3School, the "object" tag is not yet supported by IE.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp

A good alternative for browser who don't support the "object" tag would be the "embed" tag.
"embed" is supported by all major browser.

Comment: Like most things IE supports, it does it poorly to the point of uselessness, unlike modern browsers. "embed" works but it is not part of the HTML standard.

Comment: Now in 2015, the object tag is supported in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new YouTube embedding code

```
<iframe width="280" height="215" src="http://youtube.com/embed/$videoId" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

That will take care of everything.

Comment: the problem he's having is that a video is not being displayed in two browsers, changing one line makes it work everywhere, how is that not responding to his question?

Comment: an answer before me told him that the code was not supported, so I gave him working code
i can copy and paste if you wish